# How to write data from SSIS to Googlespreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, ssis-2012

I am new to all this and I am trying to write data google spreadsheet. Is that possible and if so can some one help me. Thank you.

Comment: Suggest you post details of what you have discovered so far and what problem you have hit. Just asking "Please help me" tends to get down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Am sure it is possilbe, one has an API and the other allows ODBC. That should be all you need. Suggest you hunt around for example code. There is a good java example for the spreadsheet API here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/data/spreadsheet/CellFeed.java?r=51